# XPath for groups of related elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am trying to get the information `<l7:Name>` and corresponding all `<l7:IssuerName>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<l7:List xmlns:l7="http://ns.l7tech.com/2010/04/gateway-management">  
    <l7:Item> 
        <l7:Name>services.company.int</l7:Name>  
        <l7:Id>00000000000000000000000000000004:-services.company.int</l7:Id>  
        <l7:Type>SSG_KEY_ENTRY</l7:Type>  
        <l7:TimeStamp>2018-08-28T10:25:04.615-05:00</l7:TimeStamp>  
        <l7:Link rel="self" uri="https://10.154.244.13:443/restman/1.0/privateKeys/00000000000000000000000000000004:-services.company.int"/>  
        <l7:Resource> 
            <l7:PrivateKey alias="-services.company.int" keystoreId="00000000000000000000000000000004" id="00000000000000000000000000000004:-services.company.int"> 
                <l7:CertificateChain> 
                    <l7:CertificateData> 
                        <l7:IssuerName>CN=MC Access Management sub CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>  
                        <l7:SerialNumber>83060681499471284401614700485002472352</l7:SerialNumber>  
                        <l7:SubjectName>DC=net,DC=company,O=company WorldWide - CentralAuth,OU=xmlgw-auth-client,CN=services.company.int</l7:SubjectName>  
                    </l7:CertificateData>  
                    <l7:CertificateData> 
                        <l7:IssuerName>CN=Access Management root CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>  


                    </l7:CertificateData>  
                    <l7:CertificateData> 
                        <l7:IssuerName>CN=Access Management root CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>  

                    </l7:CertificateData> 
                </l7:CertificateChain>  
                <l7:Properties> 
                    <l7:Property key="keyAlgorithm"> 
                        <l7:StringValue>RSA</l7:StringValue> 
                    </l7:Property> 
                </l7:Properties> 
            </l7:PrivateKey> 
        </l7:Resource> 
    </l7:Item>  
    <l7:Item> 
        <l7:Name>directory-company-com</l7:Name>  
        <l7:Id>00000000000000000000000000000004:--directory-company-com</l7:Id>  
        <l7:Type>SSG_KEY_ENTRY</l7:Type>  
        <l7:TimeStamp>2018-08-28T10:25:04.615-05:00</l7:TimeStamp>  

        <l7:Resource> 
            <l7:PrivateKey alias="--directory-company-com" keystoreId="00000000000000000000000000000004" id="00000000000000000000000000000004:--directory-company-com"> 
                <l7:CertificateChain> 
                    <l7:CertificateData> 
                        <l7:IssuerName>CN=PRD company 3DS1 Issuer Sub CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:IssuerName>  

                        <l7:SubjectName>CN=.directory.company.com,OU=gateway-signing,O=company Worldwide,C=US</l7:SubjectName>  

                    </l7:CertificateData>  
                    <l7:CertificateData> 
                        <l7:IssuerName>CN=PRD company Identity Check Root CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:IssuerName>  
                        <l7:SerialNumber>231453887433606512122984068379445229638</l7:SerialNumber>  
                        <l7:SubjectName>CN=PRD company 3DS1 Issuer Sub CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:SubjectName>  

                    </l7:CertificateData>  
                    <l7:CertificateData> 
                        <l7:IssuerName>CN=PRD company Identity Check Root CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:IssuerName>  

                        <l7:SubjectName>CN=PRD company Identity Check Root CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:SubjectName>  

                    </l7:CertificateData> 
                </l7:CertificateChain>  
                <l7:Properties> 
                    <l7:Property key="keyAlgorithm"> 
                        <l7:StringValue>RSA</l7:StringValue> 
                    </l7:Property> 
                </l7:Properties> 
            </l7:PrivateKey> 
        </l7:Resource> 
    </l7:Item>  
</l7:List>
```

I have tried this `/l7:List/l7:Item/l7:Resource/l7:PrivateKey/l7:CertificateChain/l7:CertificateData/l7:IssuerName`
 and `/l7:List/l7:Item/l7:Name`.

I am struggling to correlate both.

Any advise would be helpful.

---

### Update

**expecting output**

```
 <l7:Name>services.company.int</l7:Name>  

<l7:IssuerName>CN=MC Access Management sub CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>
<l7:IssuerName>CN=Access Management root CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>
```

Comment: Does `//l7:Name` select nothing while `//*[local-name()="Name"]` selects something?

Comment: //*[local-name()="Name"] does gives all the names. but I am for Name and corresponding IssuerName between Resource

Comment: And `//l7:Name` selects nothing?

Comment: It also gives same output. List of all the l7:Name

Comment: Ok, so that establishes that it's not a namespace issue.  And I see you've added the expected output.   Good progress.   Keep in mind that XPath *selects*.  If you want to *transform* or rearrange that which you've selected, you'll need to step up to XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/l7:List/l7:Item//*[self::l7:Name or self::l7:IssuerName]
```

will select

```
<l7:Name>services.company.int</l7:Name>
<l7:IssuerName>CN=MC Access Management sub CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>
<l7:IssuerName>CN=Access Management root CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>
<l7:IssuerName>CN=Access Management root CA,OU=Global Information Security,O=company WorldWide,DC=company,DC=net</l7:IssuerName>
<l7:Name>directory-company-com</l7:Name>
<l7:IssuerName>CN=PRD company 3DS1 Issuer Sub CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:IssuerName>
<l7:IssuerName>CN=PRD company Identity Check Root CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:IssuerName>
<l7:IssuerName>CN=PRD company Identity Check Root CA,OU=company Identity Check Gen 3,O=company,C=US</l7:IssuerName>
```

which, I believe, satisfies your request for

> the information `<l7:Name>` and corresponding all `<l7:IssuerName>`

Answer (score 1):

That's not an attribute, that's a namespace.  Look up xpath & namespaces.

Here is a quick code to atleast find "l7:issuername":

```
//*[name()='l7:issuername']
```

which finds 6, throw them into an array and do what you want with them.

Good luck!

As kjhughes stated or you can do this.

```
//*[name()='l7:IssuerName' or name()='l7:Name']
```

Comment: Thanks for sending the Xpath but I am able to get that individually. However was wondering it was possible to let the list all  Names and IssueName

Comment: Testing `name()` for equality with some string is poor practice because namespace prefixes are unpredictable. Rather than `[name()='xxxxx']`, always write `[self::xxxxx]` (at least, if you're testing elements - attributes are a bit different).